Как отделить touchmove по элементу от touchmove по документу?
Есть блок с sortable, с телефона если свайпнуть по блоку просто для скрола то он определяет что был touchmove и по документу и по блоку, как отделить логику? Чтобы например если пользователь просто скролит страницу то sortable не включался и скролл шел дальше, а если мы конкретно решили подвигать элементы в блоке то скролл не работал?

надо код смотреть. обычно наверное дело во всплытии события и надо применить stopPropagation()

применить к чему?

к событию (точнее к e  от callback функции)
